# Another way to express "ignore the pain"

Tags: word-choice

> Jim had ignored the pain thinking it was nothing.

What are some word choices for ignore?

Comment: Jim stoically suffered in silence, thinking it was nothing.

Comment: Please see the requirements for the [word-choice](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-choice/info) tag.

Answer (score 1):

Jim disregarded, shut out, blew past ... the pain

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have quite the same meaning (it implies serious effort on Jim's part), but

> Jim **powered through** the pain.

has nearly the same meaning and commonly used.

Comment: Or pushed through.